# Modify field "comment_count" of table "wp_post"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a website on Wordpress and I'm using a PHP function to modify the 'comment_count' field in the 'wp_post' table.

I am not using comments for that Custom Post Type, so the comment_count field is always set to 0.

I am be able to write in wp_post fields 'post_mime_type' and 'menu_order' but not in 'comment_count' field.

I have tried using the wp_update_post() function but it doesn't allow me to write in 'comment_count' field. I believe this is because it is a WordPress auto-calculated field.

Is there any way to write to the comment_count field without generating any incompatibilities?

As a reference, the Publish Press Revisions plugin can write a specified value to the comment_count field.

Comment: _"I am not using comments for that Custom Post Type"_ - so why would you want to write anything into the comment_count field in the first place then? Sounds like you are trying to misuse that field for some completely unrelated purpose then, that has nothing to do with comments? In that case, you should rather use custom meta data.

Comment: Although I wrote an answer, I tend to agree with @CBroe's statement. I've seen people attempt to use that to record page views or votes on things, however you might be fighting an uphill battle and could eventually lose all of your information, for instance during some future database schema upgrade. I agree that you would probably be better served by custom meta data attached to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this in any way, but I think you can hook into `pre_wp_update_comment_count_now` and provide the value you want, then just call `wp_update_comment_count_now` normally.

```php
function my_update_comment_count($postIdToUpdate, int $newStaticCommentCount)
{
    // Make sure we only register this once for performance reasons
    static $wasRegistered = false;

    if(!$wasRegistered){
        $wasRegistered = true;
        add_filter(
            'pre_wp_update_comment_count_now',
            static function($ignore, $old, $post_id) use($postIdToUpdate, $newStaticCommentCount) {

                if($post_id === $postIdToUpdate) {
                    return $newStaticCommentCount;
                }

                return $ignore;
            },
            10,
            3
        );
    }

    wp_update_comment_count_now($postIdToUpdate);
}

my_update_comment_count(1016, 123);
```

Alternatively, if the core `get_comments_number()` function is being used, there's a hook by the same name:

```php
add_filter(
    'get_comments_number',
    static function($count, $post_id)
    {
        if($post_id === 123) {
            return 27;
        }

        return $count;
    }
);
```

I've never used comments from WordPress before, so I don't know when count updates are all triggered, and it might be better to just hook `pre_wp_update_comment_count_now` globally.

```
add_filter(
    'pre_wp_update_comment_count_now',
    static function($ignore, $old, $post_id) {
        if($post_id === 123) {
            return 27;
        }

        return $ignore;
    },
    10,
    3
);
```